# How can I have part titles always on top in beamer handout 2x1 mode

Tags: beamer, parts, handout

When displaying slides in handout 2x1 mode—that is: two slides placed vertically on a portrait-oriented A4 (or letter) page—I would like to have part titles *always* on the top of the page, even if that means adding a blank slide on the bottom of the previous page.

How can I have this done automatically?

(In some sense this is similar to having chapter starting on odd pages in books, we want the reader to look at a specific location to find a new part/chapter.)

Answer (score 0):

Load the `ifthen` package and write the following code in front of each part command:

```
\mode<handout>{\bgroup
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{}{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\begin{frame}[plain]{}
\end{frame}}
\egroup}

\part{This is a new part}
\frame{\partpage}
```

It will automatically add a blank slide whenever the part title will otherwise fall on an even page number. As `\mode<handout>` is used, this will not affect the presentation output mode.

Answer (score 0):

This can be automated by testing for the current page number in `\AtBeginPart{}`. To make sure the additional frames don't influence numbering, I suggest the `noframenumbering` option.

```
\documentclass[
  handout
]{beamer}

\author{Author}
\title{Title}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]

\AtBeginPart{%
  {
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \mode<handout>{
      \ifodd\thepage\else
        \begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
        \end{frame}    
      \fi
    }
  }
  \begin{frame}
  \usebeamertemplate{part page}
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\part{part 1}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\part{part 2}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]